# getting null value for java.time.LocalDateTime defined in jpa entity class

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-time

From my `JpaRepository` method, I am getting `null` as value for `java.time.LocalDateTime` defined in `jpa` entity class.

**Entity class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cust_detail")
public class CustDetail implements java.io.Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "dob", nullable = false,columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
    private java.time.LocalDateTime dob;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String country;
    public CustDetail() {
    }


}
```

**repository**

```
public interface CustDetailRepository extends JpaRepository<CustDetail, Integer>{
        CustDetail findByCity(String city);
}
```

**controller**

```
@Autowired
CustDetailRepository custRepo;
@GetMapping(value="test")
public CustDetail test(){

    CustDetail custObj=  custRepo.findByCity("JK");
    return custObj;
}
```

**Response**

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "city": "jk",
    "state": "CALF",
    "dob": null //Why am I getting null here?
 
}
```

Comment: Not an expert on JPA, but what version of JPA are you using?  This [webpage suggest](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-java-time) that you should be using `java.sql.Time` or `java.sql.Date` as the type.

Comment: spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar

Comment: I changed it to 2.2.2.RELEASE. maven update. build. Still returning null

Comment: What database engine? And *exactly* what data type of the column? (Likely you should be using `OffsetDateTime` rather than `LocalDateTime`.)

Comment: Database is mysql version 8. Column datatype is datetime.

Comment: POM file dependency is `  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  </dependency>`

Comment: Post those details as edits to your Question rather than as Comments.

Answer (score 1):

You need an `AttributeConverter` since your field in the database is `TIMESTAMP`.

```java
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class TimestampToLocalDateTimeAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Timestamp> {

    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(final LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        return localDateTime == null ? null : Timestamp.valueOf(localDateTime);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(final Timestamp sqlTimestamp) {
        return sqlTimestamp == null ? null : sqlTimestamp.toLocalDateTime();
    }
}
```

This will automatically convert all your `LocalDateTime` fields in your entities to their corresponding `TIMESTAMP` in the database and vice-versa (for read/write).

Answer (score 0):

```
@Column(name = "otp_validity", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
private LocalDateTime getOptValidity() {
    return this.otpValidity;
}
```